# Pylint isn't ignoring dummy variables

Tags: python, pylint

Pylint has a configuration option which is suppose to let you do things like this:

```
for dummy_var in range(10):
    print 'hello world'
```

Ordinarily, having an unused variable like `dummy_var` would give you a warning, but since the beginning matches the regular expression in `dummy-variables-rgx`, no warning is given. By default the value is `_|dummy`, so the following should generate no warnings:

```
for _ in range(10):
    print 'hello world'
```

The problem is that it does. It gives the warning about an invalid name "_".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had read the error message more carefully, I would have realized that I was no longer getting an unused variable warning, but a warning about a bad variable name. In other words, something like this would be fine:

```
for _unused in range(10):
    print 'hello world'
```

This is okay since it matches the regular expression in `variable-rgx`. However, the original form

```
for _ in range(10):
    print 'hello world'
```

does not work since `_` does not match the value of `variable-rgx`. In order to have no warnings for this unused and invalid variable name, the name needs to be added to the list of white-listed names in `good-names`. Once this is done, no more warnings will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my `.pylintrc`:

```
dummy-variables-rgx=^_.*
```

Comment: I also prefer this to the default. In fact just `^_` is effectively the same.